# array.map(arrow function) is not same as a function with return value?

Tags: javascript, arrays, dictionary, arrow-functions

I am learning Arrow Functions in Javascript. Impressed by the **"Shorter functions"** example or definition of arrow functions given on [Mozilla's MDN page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions).

According to the page/example-

```
var a2 = a.map(function(s){ return s.length });
```

and

```
var a3 = a.map( s => s.length );
```

do the same job! and a2 & a3 store an array of lengths of strings of `a`.

So, I took up an initiative to compare the two(`a2` and `a3`) and ended up getting the result as false (control goes to the `else` clause).

Here is my code-

```
var a = [
          "Helium",
          "Argon",
          "Neon",
          "Xenon",
          "Krypton",
          "Radon"
        ];

var a2 = a.map(function(s){ return s.length });

var a3 = a.map( s => s.length );

if (a2 == a3)
{
    console.log("equal");
}
else
{
    console.log(a2+" unequal "+a3);
}
```

I am getting this as the output in the console-

[image: output]

Even though `a2` is the same as `a3`, why am I getting a falsified answer?

Comment: has nothing to do with the two different functions ... the two arrays would not be == regardless if both were created using long or short form

Comment: They are different arrays containing the same values, therefore they are unequal.

Comment: Woah! Thanks. I will have a look at it. Thanks.